# Showing topological equivalence between two topologies

Tags: general-topology

[image]

This is what I thought about doing.

[image]

Will this work?

Also, can someone give me some other examples of topological equivalence for finite and infinite spaces? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I suspect that by group they did not mean the MSE community?

Comment: haha no man, just forget that part. :P :D

Comment: Unfortunately it does not.  The inserted part  is so faded out that it becomes too onerous to read.

Answer (score 1):

Note first that you're asked to give a definition of what *topologically equivalent* could mean. You don't give one on that sheet. So minus points for that.

All your example are infinite sets; there is no finite space among them. (you do have a finite *topology* but I think the question wants you to consider finite *spaces*.

The examples do work, for the correct definition of topologically equivalent so props for that. As you don't have a definition, you cannot actually argue if they're equivalent or not either way..

Equivalent: $[0,1), [0,\infty)$ and $(0,1]$ as subspaces of $\Bbb R$ will do. Non-equivalent  easier ones: discrete vs cofinite vs indiscrete/trivial is a thing to consider.

Comment: We already discussed about definition of topological equivalence in class, we came to a decision that if X and Y are two sets with topologies $T_X$ and $T_Y$, and there exists a one to one correspondence $f: X -> Y$, such that f(X) = f(Y) and its surjective. Then, we can say that there is a topological equivalence between the two. Also, I was thinking of using an example, where $X$ is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $Y$ is $2n \in \mathbb{N}$, then we can say that there is a topological equivalence between X and Y. If, X is $n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$, and Y is $2n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$, then they doesn't work.

Comment: I have a question: Lets say I consider $\mathbb{N}$ as the set of all positive integers, then if I take discrete topology on this, it will be the singleton set, i.e. it will contain singletons such as {1}, {2}, {5}, {7} etc, and my co-finite topology will be {1}, {5,6,7}, {2,4,6,8} which are finite and are closed in finite closed topology. So, this should not be a topological equivalence, right? Also, if I take $f(x) = |x|$, then it shouldn't be a topological equivalence.

Comment: Equivalent: [0,1),[0,∞) and (0,1] as subspaces of R will do. What is the function f: X --> Y that takes every element of [0,1)  and takes it to a corresponding element of [0,infinity)? I think we need a specific function for the space before we can claim that Tx and Ty would be topologically equivalent. Can you help me on that?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun your notion of topologically equivalence is too simple. You need a bijection $f$ between $X$ and $Y$ such that $O$ is open in $X$ iff $f[O]$ is open in $Y$. So we also have a corresponding bijection of the topologies.

Comment: $f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ will map $[0,1)$ bijectively onto $[0,\infty)$ and both $f$ and its inverse are continuous, so we have the correspondence in open sets too.

Comment: Ok, now it makes more sense to me. Thank you!!